# Linq query within a date range on several tables?

Tags: linq, signalr, spam

I'm trying to find a way to detect spam in my SignalR chat application. Every time a user sends a messsage I would like to check the amount of messages sent by that user the last 5 seconds. I have a database with 2 tables: Message and User, where messages gets logged with a MessageDate and users with UserID. There is a Many-to-One relationship between the tables (1 user per message, several messages per user).

How can I write a query to check for messages sent by a specific user the last 5 seconds?

I have tried looking for a solution online but I'm new to queries and it's hard to get everything right (the join, the range of dates, using count property and getting data models right).

The closest I've gotten is something like :

```
var db = new MessageContext();
int messageCount = (from op in db.Message
              join pg in db.User on op.UserID equals pg.UserID
              where pg.UserID == op.UserID 
                    && (a.Start.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-5) 
                        && a.Start.Date <= DateTime.Now)
              select op)
             .Count();
```

Thanks in advance, any help appriciated!

Comment: This feels like a poor solution: why search through the entire database each time? Perhaps you could have a second table, just keeping tack of time and id and removing old values every so often. That reduces the computational complexity to near constant time and simplifies your logic as well.

Comment: I suggest using Linq to Reactive Extensions. You should create a Observable for messages coming in. Seriously. DON'T USE A DATABASE LIKE THIS. Heck DON'T USE THE DATABASE AT ALL. Entity Framework is NOT the only Linq Provider in existance, and Reactive Extension is in described by many as Linq to Future Events.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Making the Message data-stream into an Observable with RX seems really smart and a good way to solve this. I don't currently have experience doing this, but there are probably good guides out there to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i don't see why you need a join at all, if you have a many to many Relationship you shouldn't need a join (you should have navigation properties) so the code should look like this:

```
var q = db.Users
   .Select(usr=>
   new
   {
       User = usr,
       LastMessages = usr.Messages
        .OrderByDescending(msg=>msg.Date)
        .Take(5)
   })
   .Where(usr=>usr.LastMessages.All(msg=>msg.UpdateDate >= 5 minutes from now)
// Here q contains all the users that have posted 5 messages or more in the last 5 minutes as well as those last messages.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the relationship is one-to-many (1 user per message, several messages per user). Any idea of how this changes the code?

Comment: It doesn't. The code is meant for exactly that : 1 user = multiple messages, 1 message = 1 user

Comment: If anyone ever reads this again, here's what I ended up with:

`var query = context.Messages.Where(p => p.MessageDate > EntityFunctions.AddSeconds(DateTime.Now, -10)).Count();`